# java.lang.VerifyError in ktor server POST in full stack tutorial

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

In the official kotlin tutorial https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-full-stack-app.html

I have a ktor server running, and when I do a GET I get the correct json response. When I POST:

```
POST http://localhost:9090/shoppingList
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "desc": "Peppers ",
  "priority": 5
}
```

The server returns a 500 with this error:

```
2023-01-10 08:53:06.605 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO  ktor.application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:9090
2023-01-10 08:53:12.317 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] ERROR ktor.application - Unhandled: POST - /shoppingList
java.lang.VerifyError: class kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder overrides final method kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(Lkotlinx/serialization/descriptors/SerialDescriptor;ILkotlinx/serialization/DeserializationStrategy;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at ...
```

This is just the first part of the tutorial for building a full stack web app in Kotlin so I'd like to work out of the tutorial or I am missing something.

Server code below but this is also copy and paste right out of the turorial and using the tutorial git repo

```
val shoppingList = mutableListOf(
    ShoppingListItem("Cucumbers ", 1),
    ShoppingListItem("Tomatoes ", 2),
    ShoppingListItem("Orange Juice ", 3)
)
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 9090) {

        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        install(CORS) {
            allowMethod(HttpMethod.Get)
            allowMethod(HttpMethod.Post)
            allowMethod(HttpMethod.Delete)
            anyHost()
        }
        install(Compression) {
            gzip()
        }
        routing {
            route(ShoppingListItem.path) {
                get {
                    call.respond(shoppingList)
                }
                post {
                    shoppingList += call.receive<ShoppingListItem>()
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                }
                delete("/{id}") {
                    val id = call.parameters["id"]?.toInt() ?: error("Invalid delete request")
                    shoppingList.removeIf { it.id == id }
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                }
            }
        }


        routing {
            get("/hello") {
                call.respondText("Hello, API!")
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because the main branch of the tutorial repo is out of date and needs its dependencies updated per this issue: https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/jvm-js-fullstack/issues/21